# Can I Create Component of App in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have create one App in React Native in which having stackNavigation, BlinkID and others npm modules are there. The App is working fine.

Now, I want to create this App as Component so that user can import inside their own app and inside the render method adding my App component will load my App.

Please help me, How can I Create component of App. And after use of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The screen that you have created is already a 'component', since you must have extended the class from React.{Component}.

If only you want to use the same elsewhere, all you must do is import the screen in another component using an import statement. Your import statement must look something like this:

```
import <YourComponent> from './src/<FileName>';
```

If that is not the case, and you want a user to be able to install your component like we install various other components, using the 'npm install' command, you must make an npm package from your component. You could read about creating an npm package [here](https://medium.com/netscape/creating-an-npm-package-for-a-component-35aea0328d41).

Comment: Not single file, I have an App and want to import.

Comment: Even if it is multiple screens, you would just have to import the entry point, where you have created the Navigator. The import statements in this entry-point file should take care of the rest.